# Is there a method like Winforms.Show ( IWin32Window owner ) in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am creating a new WPF window that I want to be parented to another existing app. I do this with the:

[Winforms.Show ( IWin32Window owner )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx)

all the time, but since this app is using a WPF Window, I am looking for a way to achieve the same thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above way is valid to do this from a WPF parent window to a WPF child window

```
Window wpfWindow = new Window(); 
wpfWindow.Owner = this;
```

If you want to have a WPF windows with a Winform parent you need to use the WindowInteropHelper class.

```
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow);
helper.Owner = winFormWindow.Handle.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. But you said "If you want to have a WPF windows with a Winform parent no need to use the WindowInteropHelper class.", you mean "you need to use" instead of "no need to use"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property of the Window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowChildWindow()
    {
        MyChildWindow window = new MyChildWindow();
        window.Owner = this; // Set owner of child window.
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what would "this" be in this case? I am using a closed source 3rd party app to act as the parent. So I can get some info from it within the app, like its handle, IWin32Window, etc.

Comment: Ah sorry, `this` is any other Window, such as the applications MainWindow.

Comment: Just checked, and the Owner is of type Window, so not sure how I can create one for the existing app using its handle or IWin32Window or its process, etc.

Comment: Think of the 3rd party app say like MS Paint. So considering I can get lots of info from it like its handle, IWin32Window, etc how can I set my WPF Window to be parented to this?

Comment: OK - I think I misunderstood your question a little, sorry. I don't have an answer for you, but I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is still useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the [answer](http://blog.stpworks.com/archive/2009/07/02/setting-wpf-dialog-owner-from-within-winforms-application.aspx).

```
   MyWpfDialog dialog = new MyWpfDialog();

   //remember, this is WinForms UserControl and its Handle property is
   //actually IntPtr containing Win32 HWND.
   new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(dialog).Owner = this.Handle;
   dialog.ShowDialog();
```